# How to receive the callaback value from a function in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a function A() which return a string and I need to receive the string and print the string using **then()** method in dart

```
Future<String> A() async {
 
  return "Hello";
}

await A().then((value) => print(value));
```

I want to get the **"Hello"** printed but it prints **null**. How to do this ?

Comment: The code you have is correct, it should print "Hello" - Do you have extra codes missing, please consider sharing them.

Answer (score 0):

`await` should be used in an `async` function. But you have used await outside of the async function.

Try removing await outside.

```
 Future<String> A() async {
 
  return "Hello";
}

A().then((value) => print(value));
```

Comment: Even with `await`, it should work.

Comment: It should work because `then` is also a future so it's basically waiting for `then` to finish executing.

Comment: if he uses await in async function then it will be ok otherwise it is throwing an error like `Error: 'await' can only be used in 'async' or 'async*' methods.`

Comment: Yes that's true, but he's not having that error - it's rather that "null" is being printed.

Comment: when I run this code it prints the string.

Comment: Yeah, add await and see if it works too.